# What is the meaning of "the reification of markets" in the mentioned context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of *the reification of markets* in the mentioned context?

> But there are implicit values at work in neoliberalism. These include
>   individualism, competition, technology, **the reification of markets** and
>   (after Adam Smith) the belief that the pursuit of self-interest leads
>   to socially beneficial results. [Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=3XAHXFpPYSIC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=But%20there%20are%20implicit%20values%20at%20work%20in%20neoliberalism.%20These%20include%20individualism,%20competition,%20technology,%20the%20reification%20of%20markets%20and%20(after%20Adam%20Smith)%20the%20belief%20that%20the%20pursuit%20of%20self-interest%20leads%20to%20socially%20beneficial%20results.&source=bl&ots=a9-oEF3icx&sig=Vm-zk1chySbzq5A5R10gv4z6tqs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHvNLTuMrVAhWKXRoKHbVyDJQQ6AEIJjAA)

I know the meaning of *reify*:

> to consider or represent (something abstract) as a material or
>   concrete thing: to give definite content and form to (a concept or
>   idea) [Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=3XAHXFpPYSIC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=But%20there%20are%20implicit%20values%20at%20work%20in%20neoliberalism.%20These%20include%20individualism,%20competition,%20technology,%20the%20reification%20of%20markets%20and%20(after%20Adam%20Smith)%20the%20belief%20that%20the%20pursuit%20of%20self-interest%20leads%20to%20socially%20beneficial%20results.&source=bl&ots=a9-oEF3icx&sig=Vm-zk1chySbzq5A5R10gv4z6tqs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHvNLTuMrVAhWKXRoKHbVyDJQQ6AEIJjAA)

But what it precisely means *to reify markets*?

Comment: I'm not sure, hence a comment rather than an answer, but "markets" such as the DJIA or FTSE100 are often considered to have a special significance of their own which is over and above the significance of its constituent companies. That doesn't seem entirely fallacious, but neither is it unproblematic.

Answer (score 1):

Reification, believe it or not, is a Marxist concept. The basic idea here is that markets become the dominant paradigm of society. Everything is for sale. Everyone is a profit center. The most important goal is amassing wealth. Everything else is secondary.